# How do I fix "Event loop is closed" in a discord bot

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py, event-loop

So I was trying to make a command which restarts the discord bot but I'm getting an error which I'm unable to understand, please help me out. I have literally no clue what I'm supposed to do

```
 @bot.command(name = "restart", aliases = ["r"], help = "Restarts the bot.")
    async def restart(ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f"{bot.user.name} Restarting!",
            color = bot.embed_color,
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
        )
    
        embed.set_footer(
        text = bot.footer,
        icon_url = bot.footer_image
        )
        await bot.log_channel.send(embed = embed)
    
        await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
        await bot.logout()
```

Here's the error message I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0000017711E99550>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 719, in call_soon
  File "C:\Python86\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: This code only logs the bot out. How are you starting the bot again?

Comment: With a bat file

Comment: We don't know what this bat file looks like, nor how the rest of your Python code looks like. Please edit your question so it is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)